# Merging two object arrays by removing duplicates Javascript Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, merge, duplicates

How to merge two object arrays with no two elements with same key 'id'?

```
var array1 = [{id:"1", expected:"aaa", actual:"xxx"}, {id:"2", expected:"bbb", actual:"yyy"}];
var array2 = [{id:"1", expected:"kkk", actual:"xxx"}, {id:"4", expected:"ccc", actual:"zzz"}];
```

And the result array should be,

```
var array3 = [{id:"1", expected:"kkk", actual:"xxx"}, , {id:"2", expected:"bbb", actual:"yyy"}, {id:"4", expected:"ccc", actual:"zzz"}];
```

The element with id "1" should be added from array2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....
First merge them , then remove duplicate

```
$.merge(array1, array2);

var existingIDs = [];
array1 = $.grep(array1, function(v) {
    if ($.inArray(v.id, existingIDs) !== -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        existingIDs.push(v.id);
        return true;
    }
});
```